# When does Vertigo's villain action happen?

Tags: legendary-marvel

I recently got Legendary: Dark City and it seems like there's a misprint on the Vertigo card from the Marauder villains.

Her card says: Each player discards their hand then draws as many cards as they discarded.

Unfortunately it lacks a designation of either **Fight,** **Escape,** or **Ambush,** so we had no idea when the effect was supposed to take place. Has any official word come out on which trigger her power works off of?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to a developer from Upper Deck on [this BoardGameGeek post](http://www.boardgamegeek.com/article/12598741#12598741) Vertigo's power should be a **Fight** effect.

Comment: thank you very much, the instructions say to use her fight effect for a fight/ambush and escape