# Does Upper Deck maintain an official errata for Legendary: A Marvel Deck Building Game?

Tags: legendary-marvel

Given that there are errors on some cards, as indicated by [this question](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/29391/when-does-vertigos-villain-action-happen), is there an official errata list from Upper Deck? The closest I could find is on [Board Game Geek](https://boardgamegeek.com/filepage/92138/unofficial-collected-faq-clarifications-and-errata), but this list is a collection of notes from their forums and hasn't been updated since February of 2014.

Comment: While that errata on BGG is unofficially _maintained_, the answers in it are as official as you can get since they come directly from two of Upper Deck's game developers.

Comment: @winterblood True. I guess that leaves the age of the document as the main issue here.

Comment: From reading through the last few comments, there may be an update to it sometime soon, hopefully once some errata has been gathered for the recently released Captain America expansion.

Answer (score 2):

Officially they maintain a [Facebook page](https://www.facebook.com/LegendaryDBG) and [twitter account](https://twitter.com/LegendaryDBG) for Legendary DBGs

but there is no official Errata currently being maintained.

Answer (score 1):

The closest thing to an official errata are the updates/comments made by the designer. You can find them here: https://boardgamegeek.com/filepage/92138/unofficial-collected-faq-clarifications-and-errata